# Performance: Better to search in javascript arrays or to use Cordova-sqlite-storage in ionic?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a question concerning performance. I build a simple Entity and Store structure in my ionic 1.3 app. Basically the store contains an array which itself contains the entities which are javascript objects. To persist my data I use [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

Now my question is what is faster to do on a mobile device:

1. Find some entity by iterating the store's array of entities until I found the entity I searched for.
2. Use Cordova-sqlite-storage's find functions.

At the first glance both methods have disadvantages. Iterating over a javascript array and searching for some object in there every time I search an entity seems to be bad. But the sqlite database lives and runs on the hard disk drive of the mobile devices which possibly could be even worse (unless the database would live in the memory if retrieved from the hard disk once which is not the case if I understood the docs from the plugin correctly).

So which method would you use? Any help is highly appreciated!